# Creating a radial progress bar with css animation on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I've had a big problem trying to achieve this. I don't understand how to animate something so that it turns in a circle so I grabbed a working one from [Circle Progress Bar](http://css-shapes.xyz/radial-progress-bar) and am trying to find a way to make it animate on button click using jquery. I tried using [this](https://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/) tutorial but have no idea how to properly incorporate it. Please help. Here is my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aueqk1d8/) though it doesn't come close to working.

```
.progress {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:#fff;
    border:2px solid #000;
    position:relative;
    margin:50px;
    border-radius:50%;
    overflow:hidden;
    transform: translateZ(0px);
    display:inline-block;
}
.activatedAfter {
    -moz-animation:turn 4s linear forwards;
    -webkit-animation:turn 4s linear forwards;
    -moz-animation-delay:4s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:4s;

}
.activated {

    -moz-animation:turn 4s linear forwards;
    -webkit-animation:turn 4s linear forwards;
    -o-animation:turn 4s linear forwards;
    -ms-animation:turn 4s linear forwards;
    animation:turn 4s linear forwards;


}

@-moz-keyframes turn {
    99.9% {
        transform:rotate(180deg);
        background:tomato;
    }
    100% {
        background:#fff;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes turn {
   99.9% {
        transform:rotate(180deg);
        background:tomato;
    }
    100% {
        background:#fff;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes turn {
    99.9% {
        transform:rotate(180deg);
        background:tomato;
    }
    100% {
        background:#fff;
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes turn {
   99.9% {
        transform:rotate(180deg);
        background:tomato;
    }
    100% {
        background:#fff;
    }
}
@keyframes turn {
   99.9% {
        transform:rotate(180deg);
        background:tomato;
    }
    100% {
        background:#fff;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed `$('#progress')` to `$('.progress')` in your fiddle since 'progress' is a class and not an ID. Also, I replaced the `activatedAfter` style with the `activated:after` and `activated:before` styles from the example in the link you provided.

Also, I added the jQuery library in the code (it was not included in your fiddle)

Try this

```js
$('#battleButton').click(function() { 
 $('.progress').addClass('activated activatedAfter');
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}

.progress {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:#fff;
    border:2px solid #000;
    position:relative;
    margin:50px;
    border-radius:50%;
    overflow:hidden;
    transform: translateZ(0px);
    display:inline-block;
}
.activated:after {
    position:absolute;
    content:"";
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:-50%;
    background:tomato;
    -moz-animation:turn 4s linear forwards;
    -webkit-animation:turn 4s linear forwards;
    -moz-animation-delay:4s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:4s;
    transform-origin:100% 50%;
    z-index:1;
}
.activated:before {
    position:absolute;
    content:"";
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:50%;
    background:tomato;
    -moz-animation:turn 4s linear forwards;
    -webkit-animation:turn 4s linear forwards;
    -o-animation:turn 4s linear forwards;
    -ms-animation:turn 4s linear forwards;
    animation:turn 4s linear forwards;
    transform-origin:0% 50%;
    z-index:2;
}

@-moz-keyframes turn {
    99.9% {
        transform:rotate(180deg);
        background:tomato;
    }
    100% {
        background:#fff;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes turn {
   99.9% {
        transform:rotate(180deg);
        background:tomato;
    }
    100% {
        background:#fff;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes turn {
    99.9% {
        transform:rotate(180deg);
        background:tomato;
    }
    100% {
        background:#fff;
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes turn {
   99.9% {
        transform:rotate(180deg);
        background:tomato;
    }
    100% {
        background:#fff;
    }
}
@keyframes turn {
   99.9% {
        transform:rotate(180deg);
        background:tomato;
    }
    100% {
        background:#fff;
    }
}

button {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-color: #81ff14;
  color: #81ff14;
  border-radius: 10%;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress"></div>
<button id="battleButton">Battle</button>
```